# Side horizontal lines with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I tried using a pseudo elements to create two side lines (one from each side) of the "2" but it's not working. I read it's because `flexbox` doesn't render empty elements. How can I accomplish what I'm after?

CSS

```
.stepTag{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 4%;
    height:4%;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: #E4002B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style={{display: "flex", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"space-around"}}>
  <p className={`${s.stepTag}`}>1</p>}
    {<p className={`${s.stepTag}`}>2</p>}
  <p className={`${s.stepTag}`}>3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```css
div{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
}
.horiz{
  position: relative;
}
.horiz::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:10px;
  right: 100%;
  
  
}
.horiz::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:10px;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="pipe">1</p>
   <p class="pipe horiz">2</p>
  <p class="pipe">3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but they need to be horizontal and stretch to the 1 and 3

Comment: I am not sure what do you want, can't you simply use dashes?

Comment: I want something like this, going from the 2 to the 1 and 3: https://www.trysmudford.com/images/blog/fancy-header.jpg

Comment: Yeah! But going all the way to the 1 and 3, though I suppose I can just extend the width

Answer (score 2):

I have spent too long on this but just came up with this, I hope it helps...

HTML

```css
.title::before {
  display: inline-flex;
  content: '';
  border-top: 2px solid #9d9d9d;
  width: 150px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.title::after {
  display: inline-flex;
  content: '';
  border-top: 2px solid #9d9d9d;
  width: 150px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Your text here</h1>
```

Comment: I used this solution and improved it by making the `h1` have `display: flex` then `align-items: center`. And then I made the pseudo-elements have `flex-grow: 1` so that their width aren't hard-coded and they will adjust according to the remaining space of the assigned `width` for the `h1` element itself.

Comment: I also simply removed the height for the pseudo elements since `align-items: center` on `.title` itself does the job without any further magic values. and I removed their `margin-left` and `margin-right` and jast added `gap` to the `.title`. [Here](https://codepen.io/apappas1129/pen/gOBzKJB) is the result

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
}
.horiz{
  position: relative;
}
.horiz::before, .horiz::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:10px;
  right: 100%;  
}
.horiz::after{
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="pipe">1</p>
   <p class="pipe horiz">2</p>
  <p class="pipe">3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Jone, thanks for the answer but would be great that if you could explain your codes instead of just giving an answer